# What is this C++ Syntax when declaring a class?

Tags: c++, syntax, semantics

I occasionally run into this type of syntax when looking through open source code and was wondering what it's for, or what it's even called for that matter.

I have crawled the internet many a times before but simple contrived examples never had it nor explained it.

It looks like this

```
class SomeIdentifier ClassName { 
...
}
```

My question is what is **SomeIdentifier** ?

Comment: example please. I think it is just some macros though.

Comment: This is not a valid C++ syntax (unless you are talking about some compiler-specific declaration specifier). Are you sure you reproduced the syntax you saw correctly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Generally this would be something like that

```
#define SomeIdentifier __declspec(dllexport)
```

It is for support of MS dlls where you must specify explicitly every class
that is used in interface.

And `SomeIdentifier` would be something like

FOO_BAR_EXPORT

Comment: Yes that makes perfect sense in my context! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You probably missed a ':' between SomeIdentifier and ClassName
It might be like this:

```
class SomeIndentifier : ClassName{

};
```

Well, this means the class SomeIdentifier privately inheirits class ClassName!
Google out 'Inheritance in C++' for more..

Comment: Sorry I should of mentioned that it is not when a class is inheriting from a base class. That is why it is quite confusing me.